# How to use tcpdump to get the device info in the network?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I am able to get the packets in the network by tcpdump.I want to get the device info like computer name,its model name ,OS running on it etc.
Is it possible by using tcpdump packets .

I got the mac address (by arp),IP but which layer protocol giving this above information what I want.

Can you tell me how to use this dumped data to get my required data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but which layer protocol giving this above information what I want

The details you mention aren't present in network data - for example there's no point in a TCP segment advertising "Windows XP emitted this.". At most you can use tools like `nmap` that try to guess the OS based on subtle network engine implementation differences.